# R, if number in one table belongs to range in another

Tags: r

I got 2 tables. The 1st one looks like:

```
V1 V2
128 1.0000  
139 0.9375
141 1.0000
```

The 2nd one looks like:

```
V1 V2 V3
gene    90  100
mRNA    120 129
CDS 130 139
CDS 140 150
```

V2 and V3 in 2nd table are borders of range (e.g. 90:100, 120:129 etc)
So i need to compare number from V1 of the 1nd table if it belongs to any range. If it does, i need to rbind these rows together.
So it would look like

```
V1.1 V2.1 V1.2 V2.2 V3.2
128 1.0000 mRNA 120 129
139 0.9375 CDS 130 139
141 1.0000 CDS 140 150
```

Or smth.

The problem is these tables are really big (~5G each).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess best solution is `cbind()`. Fast and very well performing even for big tables.

Comment: cbind will not perform the intersection though

Comment: Could you please tell how many rows are there in both your tables? Also, your file doesn't seem to have chromosome id in there.. which seems a bit odd.. Could you explain your data a bit? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the size of your data sets, I would suggest `foverlaps` in the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
##
setDT(d1)
setDT(d2)
##
setnames(d2,c("V1.y","V2.y","V3.y"))
setkeyv(d2,c("V2.y","V3.y"))
##
setnames(d1,c("V1.x","V2.x"))
d1[,V11:=V1.x]
##
Merged <- foverlaps(
  x=d1,y=d2,
  by.x=c("V1.x","V11"),
  type="within")
Merged[,V11:=NULL]
##
R> Merged
   V1.y V2.y V3.y V1.x   V2.x
1: mRNA  120  129  128 1.0000
2:  CDS  130  139  139 0.9375
3:  CDS  140  150  141 1.0000
```

where I appended `.x` and `.y` just for clarity. `foverlaps` is primarily intended for joining over two ranges, one in each of the tables used, so it requires that `by.x` specifies two (different) columns in the `x` object. The only way I know of to get around this in situations like this, where we want to one column of `x` to be in the range of two columns of `y`, is to create a temporary duplicate column. This is the purpose of `d1[,V11:=V1.x]`; which is removed afterwards.

**Data:**

```
d1 <- read.table(
  text="V1 V2
128 1.0000  
139 0.9375
141 1.0000",
  header=TRUE)
d2 <- read.table(
  text="V1 V2 V3
gene    90  100
mRNA    120 129
  CDS 130 139
  CDS 140 150",
  header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldn't do this in R, although it's probably possible with one of the bioconductor packages like GRanges. Rather I would convert the files to [BED format](http://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat.html#format1), sort them (with sort -k1,1 -k2,2n) and use [bedtools intersect](http://bedtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html) , something like

```
intersectBed -a tbl1.bed -b tbl2.bed -wa -wb -sorted > merged.bed
```